# MySQL: Range based on rows in external table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am using MySQL to solve this problem. I need to give points to a user based on the total time spent by him on a question. I have calculated the time spent by the user. Let's say it is in **user_time** table.

```
user_id    question_id time_spent
      1         1         7
      1         2         50
      2         1         11
```

My points are range based:

```
[0-10) seconds: 100 points, 
[10-20) seconds: 300 points, 
[20-30) seconds: 500 points, 
[30, inf): 1000 points
```

Exact 10 seconds will fetch me 300 points. Though, the changes of an exact number would be low given that I am computing from the system clock difference.

This information is currently scored in an external table **points_table**

```
time_spent points
0          100
10         300
20         500
30         1000
```

I need a query which finds out which range the seconds belong to and give me that result.

```
user_id question_id points
1       1           100
1       2           1000
2       1           300
```

I tried thinking of different type of joins but couldn't think of one which will answer this specific requirement.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: is 20 seconds 300 points or 500 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is a correlated subquery.  Something like this:

```
select ut.*,
       (select pt.points
        from points_table pt
        where pt.time_spent <= ut.time_spent
        order by pt.time_spent desc
        limit 1
       ) as points
from user_time ut
```

Comment: Updated the question - added an extra layer which was probably complicating things

Comment: I think I was doing a wrong join as a precursor to this step. Changed my entire code to do the joins first and then do this correlated subquery - I think it will work properly. Sorry for all the confusion and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ut.user_id, ut.time_spent, A.points 
FROM user_time ut 
INNER JOIN (SELECT p1.time_spent AS time_spent1, 
                   p2.time_spent AS time_spent2, 
                   p1.points 
            FROM points_table p1 
            INNER JOIN points_table p2 ON p1.time_spent < p2.time_spent 
            GROUP BY p1.time_spent
           ) AS A ON ut.time_spent BETWEEN A.time_spent1 AND A.time_spent2
```

Comment: Dont u think Gordon's answeer is less complex doing same stuff?

Comment: I agree with @jQuery.PHP.JAVA.net. I don't we need to join the points_table. The 2 tables are independent

Answer (score 0):

For another take on this, you could achieve the same result without having the points table:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN time_spent >= 30 THEN 1000
    WHEN time_spent >= 20 THEN 500
    WHEN time_spent >= 10 THEN 300
    ELSE 100
  END 'Points'
FROM user_time;
```

Comment: Yes, we also thought of this approach but didn't want to hardcode it in queries, in case we have to change it later

Comment: Makes perfect sense and is something that I considered. Just wanted to provide an optional way to look at it.